# Creation of s3 snapshot repository fails with exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

When trying to create an elasticsearch s3 snapshot respository (have the aws plugin installed), I get the following exception:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/es_backup' -d '{
"type": "s3",
"settings": {
    "bucket": "ops-backups",
    "region": "us-west",
    "access_key": "<key>",
    "secret_key": "<key>"
    }
}'


[internal:admin/repository/verify]]; nested: RepositoryMissingException[[es_backup] missing];
```

My s3 bucket permissions look ok...why would it complain about a repository being missing if I'm creating it?

Comment: I don't think the curl is used for create new bucket in s3, that's why it complains there is no the backup `ops-backups`

Comment: us-west isn't a valid region - you probably mean us-west-1 (California) or us-west-2 (Oregon)

Comment: does  "elasticsearch.yml" file have similar configuration on all nodes? I was also facing similar issue, but In my case, this error got fixed when I put same configuration in all the nodes. Earlier I had missed putting cloud access key, secret key, bucket details etc. in one of the data node's elasticsearch.yml.file.